# Is it possible to set custom permission request using cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, permissions

I am building a cordova application that requires permission to access location, camera, etc. I would like to show a custom message to the user when requesting permission to access the data. I thought about showing the message before requesting the permission, but I am not sure how to do that on older versions of android, which request the permissions at installation. Is there any way to show a custom request for permissions that will work across android and ios?

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the message before requesting permission you can make use of the [Cordova diagnostics plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin)

This plugin allows you to check if the permission has already been granted or not, based on that you can display the dialog/alert to the user with your custom message depicting : "Hey, our app needs this permission to perform this" in a similar way.

Also no need to worry for android versions below 6.0 since the defined permissions get automatically granted after the application is installed.

Yes this plugin works for both android and iOS

PS : The permission text to be displayed can be modified for iOS but not for android. For iOS it can be updated in the project's .plist file or using a parameter mentioned in the config.xml for the plugin